# Covert python OrderedDict to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, ordereddict

My record, an `OrderedDict`, looks like this:

`my_record = OrderedDict([ (u'FIR_ID', '111249'), (u'FIR_TYPE', 'ORG')])`

I need to load this to a database, so I'd like to convert the data set into a dataframe, and then, into a CSV file, to facilitate db load. But, when I do `type(my_record)`, I get:

```
<class 'pg.mod.results'>
```

which means it is a class object. If it was of type `collections.OrderedDict`, I could just do a `DataFrame(my_record)`. I am using Python 2.x. What can I convert this `OrderedDict` to a `DataFrame`?

**Edit**

Thanks to nosklo's code, the errors are gone; the column headers are there but the values are missing. I extracted 10 records which look like this:

```
[<ravenpackapi.models.results.Result at 0x118caadd0>,
 <ravenpackapi.models.results.Result at 0x118caad90>,
 <ravenpackapi.models.results.Result at 0x118e1a950>,
...,  <ravenpackapi.models.results.Result at 0x118da8750>]
```

Then, the csv.DictWriter() produces a csv with this content:

```
<Field: TIMESTAMP_UTC>,<Field: RP_STORY_ID>,<Field: RP_ENTITY_ID>,...,<Field: ENTITY_TYPE>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

which looks like the complete list of keys. And there are many rows of ',,,,' at the end of the file indicating that values are missing.

**Update**

My current code is this:

```
records = list(records)
with open('/Users/.../.../RP_test_5.txt', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.DictWriter(f, 
        ravenpackapi.models.fields.ANALYTICS_FIELDS,
        extrasaction='ignore') 
    cf.writeheader()
    cf.writerows(r.data for r in records)
```

Since the values are missing, I tried:

```
for r in records: r.data
```

which successfully gave me the dictionary I need. So I don't understand why, I can't write any values to my csv. Could it be that

```
ravenpackapi.models.fields.ANALYTICS_FIELDS
```

gives me

```
[<Field: TIMESTAMP_UTC>,
 <Field: RP_STORY_ID>,
 <Field: RP_ENTITY_ID>,
 <Field: ENTITY_TYPE>,...
```

whereas, **r.data** from

```
for r in records: r.data
```

gives me

```
 {u'RP_ENTITY_ID': u'91C82E',
 u'RP_POSITION_ID': None,
 u'RP_SOURCE_ID': u'C98333',
 u'RP_STORY_EVENT_COUNT': 17,
 u'RP_STORY_EVENT_INDEX': 5,
 u'RP_STORY_ID': u'54F16F66850FB15F838629FD0C41F1CD',
 u'SOURCE_NAME': u'Ticker Report',
 u'SUB_TYPE': None,
 u'TIMESTAMP_UTC': u'2018-06-30 00:03:10.457',...,}
```

which are in different order, and/or, the keys are formatted differently?

`u'TIMESTAMP_UTC'` versus `<Field: TIMESTAMP_UTC>`

**This worked**

```
records = list(records)

for r in records: r.data

with open('/Users/.../RP_test_6.txt', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.DictWriter(f, 
        r.data.keys(),
        extrasaction='ignore') 
    cf.writeheader()
    cf.writerows(r.data for r in records)
```

I am sure there are better ways than

```
for r in records: r.data
```

and

```
r.data.keys()
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You start your question by saying your object is a `OrderedDict`, but it is not. It is a `pg.mod.results`!

If it is a dict-like object and you want to store it to a csv file, you don't need to convert it to a DataFrame at all, you can just use the `csv.DictWriter` class included in python:

```
records = list(records)

with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.DictWriter(f, records[0].keys()) 
    cf.writeheader()
    cf.writerows(records)
```

**EDIT:**

On the comments below you revealed what those objects really are - they are not OrderedDicts and for some unknown reason, the author decided to return the representation of a `OrderedDict` in the `__str__` method of `Result` objects, that is why you got confused.

Based on this https://github.com/RavenPack/python-api/blob/e3c99f5eaab7819a2087565ce0859bfb956a45cc/ravenpackapi/models/results.py#L33 the `Result` object is a custom object that holds the real data in its `.data` attribute. You can then use that attribute to do the conversion:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.DictWriter(f, 
        ravenpackapi.models.fields.ANALYTICS_FIELDS,
        extrasaction='ignore') 
    cf.writeheader()
    cf.writerows(r.data for r in records)
```

Comment: I think your feedback is going to solve my issue, but not yet. Currently, my_record is a list of these dict-like objects. I tried the code you sent me and I get error: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys' which is consistent with the fact that the objects are not of type 'dict' and therefore, don't have a key or value.

Comment: @Y.Eman I changed it to use `records` which is a list of records. It grabs the keys from the first element. What do you get in this case?

Comment: I made the change and get: Error:'Result' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: @Y.Eman maybe it is time to tell us where those objects come from - there must be a way to get a list of keys to pass to `DictWriter`

Comment: @Y.Eman ugh! terrible practice: return a representation of a different object in `__str__` to confuse the programmer using the API... *sigh* oh well. The author should provide a `to_dict()` method or something.

Comment: The last line of your code give error: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: {u' RP_POSITION_ID' : NONE, u'GROUP', None, u'ENTITY_NAME': u'Time Warner', ....} which is all of data.

Comment: @Y.Eman it means the `.data` attribute has more keys than the `OrderedDict` response you were getting before from `__str__`. I added the `extrasaction='ignore'` to the `DictWriter` instantiation to ignore those extra keys. Try it now

Comment: Now, the last line gives me AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get'?

Comment: Doesn't make sense @Y.Eman - edit the question and add the full error traceback?